# Modern bike security, a lock with GPS and SIM card?

Tags: lock, security, gps

These days many things are getting GPS and these things often also have a SIM card, so they can connect to the internet. (I think some call this internet of things)

Is there any bike lock out there which incorporates these ideas?

Perhaps a device that sends a signal every i.e. 5s to the internet, and I can think of an app on my phone which then checks for this signal often. And trigger an alarm in case the signal isn't received.

Comment: Though it may be possible but it would require a battery that needs recharging and might trigger false alarms if ever it ran out of power. And GPS will not work indoors.

Comment: It wouldn't seem like a very helpful thing to have:  You get an alert, rush to where you left the bike, and find the destroyed lock on the ground, but no bike.  There are trackers deigned to be concealed in the bike, and used in addition to a lock.

Comment: Doubtless there are plenty on Kickstarter etc, but that's a sign that the idea is subtly flawed.  Consider that any electronic lock needs a backup for when it goes flat, which makes it into a keyed lock anyway.

Comment: @Criggie while I agree the idea is flawed, the principle that being on Kickstarter is a sign of that isn't generally true. Can be, but not always.

Comment: @stijn fair enough - while there are some good products that come through crowdfunding, they're not in the majority.  Different does not mean good.

Answer (score 4):

Sophisticated bicycle GPS trackers have been on the market for a while now. You can even get some that can be hidden in the seatpost or handlebars and the battery life will be different on different trackers and how regular you want the  GPS reporting.

Smart locks do exist, but having a conventional lock, one that isn't permenantly fixed to the bike, is not much use (IMO) in the event of a theft, thiefs rarely take the broken locks with them, and by the time you get to the location of the theft, they will likely be gone.

A bike lock such as the [I lock IT](https://ilockit.bike/en/) might be something to consider, although without knowing the bike you plan to protect, I can't advise on compatibility.

I don't know of any conventional bike locks with SIM and GPS functionalities, there are some with bluetooth-like alert systems, but you would have to be within Bluetooth distance of the bike.

You can also consider GPS tracking bicycle lights. Although, if you live in a place with bike light theft is high, this might not be an option.

Personally, I would invest in good bicycle insurance (and Gold Standard lock) before looking for any GPS systems. Bare in mind that difference insurers will have differe policies on claiming for bike theft, triple check all the small details required before thinking you are covered. This might include what lock you use, what you lock the bike too and where on the bike you place the lock.